# Gridfs and mongoose file upload

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I have ran into a problem with gridfs file upload.
Basically I get this bizzare error and I have yet not found solution for solving this problem.

Here is my code that should deal with file upload:

```
var path = require('path');
var router = require('express').Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var serverConfig = require('../config.js');
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty')();
var fs = require('fs');
var GridFs = require('gridfs-stream');


var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var mongoDriver = mongoose.mongo;
var gfs = new Gridfs(db, mongoDriver);

router.post('/upload', multiparty, function(req, res){
    console.log("file was posted");
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: req.files.file.name + Date.now(),
        mode: 'w',
        content_type: req.files.file.mimetype,
        metadata: req.body
    });
    fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path).pipe(writestream);
    writestream.on('close', function(file){
        res.status(200).json(file);
    })
})
```

When trying to run my code, I get this error:

```
if (!db) throw new Error('missing db argument\nnew Grid(db, mongo)');
           ^

Error: missing db argument
new Grid(db, mongo)
```

Im using Mongoose version 4.11.12 and Gridfs-stream version 1.1.1 
**Does anybody know what should be done to get this thing working?**

Comment: Looks like `mongoose.connection.db` is not set, what does your connection string look like?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `mongoose.connection.db` is not pulling in the database name as it maybe missing on the connection string, your connection string should look like `'mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...'` where database is the database you want to connect to.

alternatively you can just replace

```
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var mongoDriver = mongoose.mongo;
var gfs = new Gridfs(db, mongoDriver);
```

with

```
var mongoDriver = mongoose.mongo;
var gfs = new Gridfs("myDatabase", mongoDriver);
```

Comment: Currently I am using following connection string: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/someDb'. (mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/someDb')). I read from the mongoose documentation that this is the minimum needed requirement. The connection is done in another file aswell but correct me if I am wrong this should not have effect on my problem. So is the connection string a problem in my case?